# What is another way of saying" instil fear " and "shamelessly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expression-choice

I was writing an essay and found no other way of expressing "instil fear" and "shamelessly". I am looking for ways to say these in a more formal manner.

Comment: Instil fear sounds quite formal to me already... _scare_ or _frighten_ seem a bit less so, and more commonplace. Or are you actually looking for one word that _combines_ those two things (scare and shamelessly)?

Comment: oh well i thought it could be made more formal, and no i want to combine them, they are separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among possible options I suggest:

[Intimidate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Intimidate):

> - To fill with fear, make timid.
> - To coerce or inhibit by or as if by threats.

[Outrageously](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/outrageous):

> - Grossly offensive to decency or morality.
> - Being well beyond the bounds of good taste: outrageous epithets.

or [Impudently](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impudently):

> - Characterised by offensive boldness; insolent or impertinent.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

Disturb, frighten, terrify. Overtly, unabashedly (for shamelessly, obviously). Shamelessly is a difficult one - the shame emotion is, in this case, on the part of the observer of the behaviour, and whatever the behaviour is may not be perceived as something 'shameful' on the part of the protaganist/individual. If the individual concerned knows their behaviour is something shameful, then 'unabashedly' would be a reasonable fit - if they don't know how it's perceived, then 'overtly' might be better.